# A company had me sign two conflicting documents about two years apart. Which one would apply?

Tags: medical-marijuana

The first was a drug policy. No drugs or alcohol period. The second said no drugs or alcohol on the job site. They got me on a drug test but I never smoke at work. Does the first document apply

Comment: Where do you work? The law varies from place to place.

Answer (score 5):

> A company had me sign two conflicting documents about two years apart. Which one would apply?

Possibly both because actually there is no conflict.

What you describe does not reflect that these documents are incompatible or inconsistent. There is no indication that the second document impliedly or explicitly replaces the first one. The second document seems just redundant so far.

Employees could likewise be required to sign a third document that only says "*no drugs or alcohol on the job site on Wednesdays*", and that does not mean that any previous documents they signed expire.

Answer (score 3):

### Doesn’t matter

Assuming the test was conducted at work, you were under the influence of drugs *on the job site* which means you fall foul of both policies.

Comment: The OP said "they got me on a drug test".  The drug test might not detect whether a person is under the influence.  It might just detect if the drug has been used within the past X days.

Comment: @James there is no conflict between the documents stated by OP.

Comment: @Trish:  I agree that the documents don't conflict with one another.  My only comment is that the OP was not necessarily "under the influence of drugs on the job site" as Dale stated.